# Passing in a file name / directory into command line in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to do some processing on whether the user enters a (1) file name, or (2) directory name into the command line.  Anything else should throw an error.  Starting with the simplest case, I wrote this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RemoveDuplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Program accepts one command-line argument.  Exiting!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        File f = new File(args[0]);
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("is directory");
        }
        else if (f.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("is file");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Shouldn't happen");
        }
    }
}
```

at the command line, I type: java RemoveDuplicates example.txt
and I get the reuslts, "Shouldn't happen."  I also tried java RemoveDuplicates "example.txt" and that doesn't work either.  So I was wondering if my code is wrong, or how I'm passing it into the command line is wrong for starters.

Secondly, how do you pass in a directory name?  Like if your directory was myDirectory, is it the same thing: java RemoveDuplicates myDirectory

Third, why if I put my File f = new File(args[0]) into a try block and have a catch block, I get a compile error about what is in my try block never throws an exception.  I thought File threw an exception? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Are you sure example.txt exists in your working directory?  Try adding the following and see what happens.

   ```
   File f = new File(args[0]);
   if (!f.exists()) {
     System.out.println("does not exist");
   }
   ```
2. You have that right.
3. Actually, I don't get this error.  How did you do the try/catch?

Comment: Yes, the file name is in the same directory where my .java and .class files are, but I get the Does not exist now that I put that in.  I tried writing a file instead, and it puts the file into this same directory, where my files lie.  Edit: I just tried it with a directory, and that seemed to work so that is good.

Comment: `example.txt` should be in the directory you run the program from, not necessarily the directory where the `.java` and `.class` files are.

Comment: For me, those are all the same directories.

Comment: Ok, I got it working now.  In my directory, it says example.txt, however, the separate file I tried writing, did not have the .txt extension, so I assumed Windows wasn't showing it since it found that file.  So I deleted .txt from the example.txt name.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> So I was wondering if my code is wrong, or how I'm passing it into the command line is 
>   wrong for starters

Is that file present in your working directory? Something which doesn't exist is neither a file nor a directory. Try creating a sample text file with the same name and then invoking your program.

> how do you pass in a directory name

Pass in a fully qualified string which represents your directory (e.g. `java MyProg "c:\testdir\mydir"`) pass in a directory path relative to your current working directory (e.g. `java MyProg testdir/mydir`)

> File f = new File(args[0]). I thought File threw an exception?

Creating a new `File` object doesn't create a physical file hence no `IOException` is thrown as you expected. It is only when you try to open a file for reading or writing a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown. Hence it's a good practice to always check for the existence of a File before using it for IO.

Answer (score 0):

1. I compiled & ran your program. It is working as expected.

C:\upul\eclipse\src\Test\src>java RemoveDuplicates RemoveDuplicates.java

is file

C:\upul\eclipse\src\Test\src>java RemoveDuplicates c:\upul

is directory

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to type java RemoveDuplicates.**java** example.txt.
2. Correct.
3. You should be able to do that as anything can throw RuntimeException which is a subclass of Exception.